# Ежегодный опрос Stack Overflow 2016

Tags: обсуждение, опрос

Открыт ежегодный опрос разработчиков!

https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016

Прохождение опроса займет у вас порядка 10 минут. Мы знаем, у вас есть много программных дефектов для исправления и задач для реализации, да и вообще, прохождение опросов не входит в описание вашей работы, так что мы крайне благодарны вам за уделенное внимание.

Также как и в [прошлом году](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015) мы будем собирать результаты в течение последующего месяца и презентуем их вам в конце. Вы сможете узнать, кто работает удаленно, кто любит работать по ночам, а кто считает себя рок–звездой, ниндзя, гуру и так далее.

А вы? [Дайте нам знать!](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016)

---

Свободный перевод публикации [@samthebrand](http://stackexchange.com/users/482412/) «[Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/)».

Comment: Кто ещё верит в инопланетян? :D

Comment: Конечно, все верят :)