# Как вы нашли работу?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

> #### Кратко
>
> Рассматривая данный вопрос, пришел к выводу, что всё-таки подобной теме не место на Stack Overflow. По сути, вопрос подразумевает ответ, который является расширенным комментарием к резюме. Резюме участника не является полезным в работе знанием. Более того, лучшим ответом на вопрос будет:
>
> - Просмотр и детальное исследование резюме лидеров сообщества.
> - Изучение [ежегодных опросов Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2281/) за разные года.
> - Просмотр вопросов по метке [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8).

Некоторое время назад, в сообществе был [поднят вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1771/) о присутствии на сайте вопросов вида «Как вы нашли работу». В обсуждении было задето два вопроса:

1. Что вообще делать со старыми вопросами, которым, согласно новым правилам сообщества, не место на сайте.
2. Что делать с конкретным вопросом и ему подобными.

**Зачем вообще что-то делать?**

- Stack Overflow на русском – это актуальная постоянно пополняемая база прикладных решений, нет смысла поддерживать более не нужную информацию (старые заброшенные вопросы).
- Stack Overflow на русском – это зеркальное отражение нашего обобщенного профессионального «я». Бардак на сайте недопустим.

#### Что делать с вопросами, которым *более* не место на сайте?

1. *Вопрос содержит ответы с уникальным опытом, который может быть полезен другим участникам*. Установить историческую блокировку.
2. *Вопрос имеет только некачественные ответы, не содержащие сколь значимую информацию*. Удалить вопрос.
3. *Вопрос имеет один или несколько ответов, не содержащих сколь значимую информацию*. Удалить все ответы не несущие смысловой нагрузки, и при необходимости собрать все ответы в один.
4. *Вопросу и ответам на него не место на сайте согласно правилам, но часть сообщества все же хочет его сохранить*. Установить блокировку, открыть обсуждение преобразования формата вопроса на Мете.

**Чего делать не стоит?**

Поддерживать неконструктивный спор. У проекта есть миссия – сделать Интернет лучшим местом для получения развернутого ответа на технический вопрос. Спорами и раздорами этой цели определенно не достичь.

#### Что делать конкретно в данном случае?

- Интересны ли вопросы вида «Как вы нашли работу» кому-либо? – *Да*.
- Есть ли место вопросам вида «Как вы нашли работу» на Stak Overflow на русском? – *Нет*.

Подобные вопросы лишь от части аналогичны вопросам про литературу. Разница заключается в том, что если спустя какое-то время конкретная книга (или другой источник) либо признается сообществом, либо нет, но нет какого-либо стандартного общепризнанного «пути разработчика» – у нас всех разные интересы и карьерные цели.

Все же, весьма вероятно, что можно пролить свет на сегодняшнюю ситуацию в отрасли совместными трудами. Для этого, можно собрать опыт по обобщенным критериям и рассмотреть перспективы в их контексте. Каждый критерий можно оценить как увеличивающий вероятность получения работы или уменьшающий.

Повторюсь, опыт поиска работы у каждого инженера свой, компании – разные. Наша задача – рассмотреть, как обстоят дела в общем. Возможно, у нас получится собрать опыт участников сообщества здесь, на Мете, а результат можно будет попробовать резюмировать в обновление к вопросу.

#### Что может быть интересно тем, кто задает вопросы про работу?

- Как состоявшиеся успешные коллеги нашли работу?
- Какие навыки необходимы, чтобы устроиться на первую работу?
- Какие технологии стоит изучать?
- В какой ВУЗ идти учиться?
- Стоит ли вообще идти в ВУЗ?
- Какие навыки необходимы, чтобы повысить свою квалификацию как инженера?
- Что следует изучать для углубления в текущую область?
- В какую сторону расширять профессиональный кругозор?

Типичный вопрос: У меня есть `{какой-то}` опыт, я студент `{N-го}` курса, знаю `{Языки}`, опыта нет, подскажите, `{как устроиться}/{как поступить}/{какие перспективы есть в направлении}`?

#### Возможные критерии для описания опыта

1. Образование

   - Являетесь ли вы студентом.
   - На каком курсе учитесь.
   - Есть ли профильное образование.
2. Реальные знания

   - Участие в любительский проектах.
   - Наличие проектов с открытым исходным кодом.
   - Опыт работы в той или иной форме.
3. Местоположение

   - В каком городе вы планируете работать.
   - Планируете ли работать удаленно или из офиса.
4. Время на поиск

   - За какое время вы хотите найти работу.
   - В какой момент вы хотите устроиться на работу (например, конец учебного года или середина).
5. Отклик на вакансию

   - С выполнением тестового задания или без выполнения тестового задания.
   - Требуется ли, чтобы у компании было имя.
   - Если ли требование к рабочему пространству.
6. Время на работе время

   - 10-и/20-и/30-и/40-а часовая рабочая неделя.

Если вы хотели бы поделиться с сообществом вашим опытом становления разработчика, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его ответе на этот вопрос. Постарайтесь включить в ваш ответ рекомендации по критериям описанным выше. Было бы здорово рассмотреть опыт в контексте профессионального уровня на момент поиска работы:

- стажера;
- младшего разработчика;
- разработчика;
- старшего разработчика;
- ведущего разработчика;
- и т. д.

Уверен, участникам находящимся на ранней стадии своего профессионального пути, будет крайне полезно знать какую литературу вы изучали на каждом из этапов, в какой последовательности.

В завершении, на мой взгляд, можно поделиться:

- самой интересной задачей встречавшейся на собеседовании;
- примерным числом проваленных интервью до настоящего момента.

Comment: Тут у вас сразу две темы. Может, разделить? Одна про предложение поделиться опытом, другая — про политику относительно таких вопросов на ru.SO (не на Мете)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вынести обсуждение по старым вопросам в отдельную публикацию точно стоит.

Comment: Все эти вопросы и ответы на них абсолютно бессмысленны и даже вредны. Я полагаю, что многие читали биографии Вашингтона, Джобса и всех прочих известных личностей. Как много из них смогли повторить путь? Ни одного. Потому что каждый путь уникален и нельзя повторить путь другого. Все ответы на подобные вопросы будут чересчур субъективны, а следовательно бесполезны и, как я уже сказал, вредны.

Answer (score 21):

> Как состоявшиеся успешные коллеги нашли работу?

Если ты что-то умеешь — работа тебя найдёт: в обозримом будущем спрос будет превышать предложение. От активности будет зависеть только то, насколько быстро достигнешь (или перепрыгнешь) свою цель.

Если ты студент, и твоя мечта — работать в гугле/майкрософте/яндексе, то мозоль им глаза всеми доступными способами, есть много возможностей.

> Какие навыки необходимы, чтобы устроиться на первую работу?

Никаких. В силу спроса берут даже ума лишённых. Вопрос только в том, сколько будут платить.

> Какие технологии стоит изучать?

В общем не повредят дискретка, алгебра и всякие прочие базовые незамысловатые предметы. Они периодически всплывают во многих задачах, поэтому знать их полезно.

Всякие глубокий матан (за пределами первого курса, где повторяют школьную программу), дифуры, матфизика и прочая заумная дребедень вам понадобятся только в том случае, если они окажутся в вашем приложении частью предметной области. Но с таким же успехом ими могут оказаться химия, лингвистика, геология или бухгалтерия, которые все вместе всё равно не встретишь.

Тут надо смотреть, что конкретно тебя интересует, и куда ты хочешь попасть. Если мечта твоей жизни — качать нефть, то полистай на досуге геологию, не повредит. Мечтаешь жить на зарплату преподавателя в универе — прокачивай матан и дифуры. Грезишь стать специалистом по безопасности — ломай по выходным сайты банков.

Что касается языков программирования, то изучить и пощупать хотя бы поверхностно стоит как можно больше. Важно знать хотя бы парочку мейнстримовых языков, без них не прожить: C++, C#, Java, Objective-C, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, PHP, Perl, VB, SQL. Полезно для здоровья знать некоторые около-мейнстримовые языки: Assembler, Swift, R, Lisp, Scala, Lua, Haskell, F#, Rust. Шансы встретить их в работе заметно меньше, но их изучение позволяет расширить сознание.

Если знаешь, что хочешь разрабатывать, то изучай соответствующие технологии, только свыкнись с мыслью, что они постоянно меняются, поэтому не рассчитывай, что можно изучить что-то одно, а потом остановиться в развитии. Если не знаешь, что хочешь — попробуй всё: и веб, и десктоп, и мобилки, и далее по списку. Что-нибудь приглянётся.

> В какой ВУЗ идти учиться?

На этот параметр покласть почти всем. Есть укуренный интерпрайз, где любят красивые бумажки, есть матанистые компании, но их больше будет интересовать ваша дипломная работа, есть странные компании, где высшее образование требуется даже у вахтёров... Но их всех можно игнорировать.

ВУЗы хороши не названиями, а преподами, и чем круче ВУЗ, тем выше вероятность встретить нормальных, а это поможет в изучении предметов. В конце концов же важны твои знания, и отсутствие громкого имени ВУЗа может компенсироваться собственной активностью, до определённого порога.

> Стоит ли вообще идти в ВУЗ?

Опять смотрим, что интересует. Если мечатешь клепать сайтики на похапэ — к чертям никакой ВУЗ не нужен. Можно после девятого класса, а то и раньше, уходить из школы и зарабатывать себе на жизнь.

Если планы средненькие, то ВУЗ — это совмещение приятного с полезным. Из полезного — знания более-менее системные, изучение распланированное, то есть не придётся копаться на википедии, ходя по сотням ссылок в попытках разобраться в какой-то области. Если в школе важно попробовать разные направления и найти любимое, то в ВУЗе важно узнать, из чего это направление состоит, чтобы потом находить нужное в разумные сроки.

Если планы наполеоновские, то сидеть на пятой точке вредно для здоровья, нужно активно изучать всё, что хоть как-то относится к нужной области. Тут универсальных ответов нет, мучай специалистов той области.

> Какие навыки необходимы, чтобы повысить свою квалификацию как инженера?
>   Что следует изучать для углубления в текущую область?
>   В какую сторону расширять профессиональный кругозор?

Сторона — это интимное дело каждого отдельного человека. А изучать надо то, чего требует работа. И совсем не факт, что оно будет относиться к математике и смежным областям.

Comment: Можно ещё добавить, что ВУЗы ещё хороши студентами, которые (дурной) пример подают -- если человек не железный Феликс, то вчерашний школьник одним интернетом не обойдётся для получения профессионального образования + спорт + соц.общение (IRL) с себе подобными.

Comment: @Squidward  Ваши прогноз "в обозримом будущем спрос будет превышать предложение" никогда не соответствовал и не будет соответствовать действительности.

Comment: @Squidward  И нет никакого спроса. Откуда у вас эти фантазии? Люди годами ищут работу, и не могут найти. Сейчас в России кризис. Так что ваши розовые фантазии расходятся с действительностью.

Comment: Весьма воодушевляющее начало. Однако комментарий т-ща Vlad from Moscow заставляет вернуться на землю.

Answer (score 8):

> Как состоявшиеся успешные коллеги нашли работу?

Если ты квалифицированный инженер, то работа тебя всегда найдёт. Если нет, то всегда можно создать работу (создать компанию). Тяжело только в первый год-два после университета, так как работодатели считают, что не бывает студентов с опытом.

Могу сказать по себе, пока учился прокачивался в направлениях C#/ASP.NET. После универа сразу нашёл работу - автоматизировал документооборот на Share Point. В течении года на этой работе осознал, что это не актуальное направление развития в наши дни, прокачивал в свободное время Java/Android. После года работы уволился и уехал в Москву, намереваясь найти работу как Android разработчик. За неделю нашёл интересную вакансию с достойной з/п. После года работы (в свободное время прокачивал геймдев) уехал с тиммейтами в другую страну и основали свою компанию.

> Какие навыки необходимы, чтобы устроиться на первую работу?

Упёртость. Конечно, если у вас опыта маловато, то вы будете хвататься за любое предложение. Но после года-двух уже стоит подавать себя как профессионала, а не как Джуниора. Год-два - это цифра из головы, всё зависит только от вас. Кто-то развивается быстрее остальных.

> Какие технологии стоит изучать?

Если бекенд девелопер, то гуглить в направлении DevOps. Плюс сейчас очень популярны всякие облака и всякие кластерные штуки, поэтому хорошо бы ознакомиться с штуками вроде Мезоса, Kubernets, Hadoop и т.п.

Если говорить про язык, то Java/node.js будут востребованы ещё долго. Можно, конечно, попробовать прокачаться в чём-то узкоспециализированном вроде Эрланга, но в России сложно найти вакансии на такой экзотике.

Из прикладного, матан пригодится.

> В какой ВУЗ идти учиться?

В России сложно получить нормального профильное IT образование. Универ просто вам мозги вправит. Есть, конечно, норм университеты вроде МИФИ, где реально много полезного, но туда попасть сложновато из глубинки.

> Стоит ли вообще идти в ВУЗ?

Да/нет. Если силы воли хватает заниматься самообразованием, то нет смысла, так как потеря времени. Если чувствуете, что вам это не по силам (самообразованием), то лучше идти в университет.

> Какие навыки необходимы, чтобы повысить свою квалификацию как
>   инженера?

Любознательность, упёртость.

> Что следует изучать для углубления в текущую область?

Смежные направления. Скажем, если вы пишете на Java, то неплохо бы изучить Scala, ибо подходы разные, неплохо мозги расширяет.

> В какую сторону расширять профессиональный кругозор?

В любую интересующую сторону. Важно не то, **что** вы изучаете, а сам факт того что вы **хотите** что-то изучать. Как только вам станет лень изучать новое, можно ставить крест на вас.

Comment: _Если нет, то всегда можно создать работу (создать компанию)._ Хм. Это вы о какой планете сейчас говорите?

Comment: @VladD про Венеру.

Comment: @Suvitruf  "Если ты квалифицированный инженер, то работа тебя всегда найдёт" - это наивное детское заблуждение.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow угу.

Comment: Я думаю если нет сил заниматься самообразованием, то лучше вообще не заниматься. Иными словами ВУЗ - всегда потеря времени.

Comment: @Flippy в ВУЗе хоть как-то попинывают студентов. Если у человека нет стимула учиться, то такие пинки порой помогают.

Comment: Про ВУЗ не согласен. Все огромные предприятия, корпорации, Газпромы, РосНефти и крупные гос.учреждения, в обязательном порядке принимают на работу лишь при наличии высшего образования. Т.е. фронт работ после увольнения (а такое сейчас часто происходит, сам работаю 3-4 года и что-то новое подыскиваю), у вас будет на порядок выше, этот фронт работ, чем у того, кто без ВУЗа - личный, печальный опыт (заброшенное высшее).