# Долой вредные метки [работа] и [опрос]!

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Всегда (если не всегда, приведите контрпример), когда задаётся вопрос с меткой [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0), можно закрывать вопрос либо с причиной "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ", либо как "не по теме". Считаю эту метку вредной и предлагаю её удалить и никогда не использовать.

Также считаю вредной метку [опрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81). Какие у нас могут быть опросы? Это сразу же закрытие вопроса по причине "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ".

Я убеждён, что у нас не должно быть меток, предрасполагающих нарушать правила.

Comment: Давайте поменяем правила.

Comment: @avp Какие именно правила вы хотите поменять?

Comment: @avp Между прочим, можете написать свой вопрос-предложение, где изложите во всех деталях, как именно следует менять правила.

Comment: Вообще нужно меньше формализма, даже в обсуждениях. А что касается "объективно верного ответа", так это просто за гранью.

Comment: @avp Я так не считаю, и абсолютно доволен текущими правилами.

Answer (score 3):

Из [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2423/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83) @NicolasChabanovsky так понимаю существующую ситуацию так: есть несколько десятков вопросов по работе. Они не по теме, но удалять их жалко. И ничего против этого не имею. Пусть будет так.

Предлагаю компромиссный выход. Сделать метку [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0) только для чтения. То есть чтобы по ней нельзя было задавать новые вопросы. <strike>При этом по ней также можно было бы находить вопросы и находить её в списке меток.</strike>

Если это технически не реализовано на данный момент, но это предложение вам по душе, то давайте предложим это на уровень выше, чтобы они добавили такой функциональность.

Добавил описание для метки [работа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0), из которого ясно, что метка существует только из-за исторических причин и использовать эту метку для новых вопросов нельзя.

Comment: Учитывая текущие планы компании (есть некий секретный, но абстрактный, план работ аж до конца 2017 года), подобного рода функционала не будет, как минимум, в ближайшее время. Более того, метки только для чтения противоречат и самой идеи коллективного управления содержимым и непрерывному поддержанию актуальной информации в базе знаний (если что–то не нужно, по мнению сообщества, необходимо удалить подобную информацию).

Comment: На сколько я понимаю результат предыдущего обсуждения на эту тему,  то мы решили либо (а) заблокировать существующие вопросы как вопросы имеющие историческое значения и запретить любые будущие вопросы по данной теме, либо (б) перенести/переписать существующие вопросы в каком–либо виде на Мету, удалив их с основного сайта вместе с метко, при необходимости.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я не совсем понимаю. То есть что делать с этими вопросами ещё обсуждается, раз есть два варианта?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky По поводу меток только для чтения немного возражу. Есть метка [tag:книги] и, как я понимаю, де-юре эта метка только для чтения. Так как в описании написано "НЕ ЗАДАВАЙТЕ НОВЫХ ВОПРОСОВ ПО ЭТОЙ МЕТКЕ". Я просто предлагаю добавить технические основы для того, чтобы не смотреть добавились ли вопросы по метке работа вручную.

Comment: Единственно возможное решение для отслеживания сейчас – подписаться на метку. На Stack Overflow нет такого, что кто–то что–то решил и это правило вошло в справку на веке. Сообщество – это живые люди. Решение о конкретных действиях принимают те, кто активны в сообществе сейчас (конечно же хотелось бы принимать во внимание предыдущий опыт). Кстати, когда–то (до перехода на новый движок) вопросы о работе были допустимы. Этот пример отлично демонстрирует, что правила меняются вместе с людьми в сообществе.

Answer (score -7):

Работу оставить и включить в тематику.

А опрос уже почистили...

Comment: Аргументируйте плиз

Comment: А можно пример хорошего вопроса по работе?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а чем плох с +27 и исторической блокировкой?

Comment: Вы правда апеллируете к вопросу который заканчивается вопросом "Так вот, какие у вас планы на свое дальнейшее будущее?" ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, сжечь тот вопрос с блокировкой

Comment: Я не считаю такие вопросы уместными на этом сайте. Пусть даже он был и будет полезен. Всего по этой теме на данный момент 89, а сколько из них удалено было с сайта за всё время? И даже не в этом дело. Почти невозможно задать вопрос по "работе" с возможностью давать объективные ответы. Эти вопросы обречены рождать десятки ответов-историй, прения, ответы-мнения, а это явно не формат.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, мы не SO с кучей народу и вопросов. У нас пока нет причин жёстко ограничивать рамки. Ну так и не будем с этим спешить. Вот когда начнут задавать бесполезные вопросы, либо когда эти вопросы начнут создавать проблемы, тогда и запрещать. Тем более, из SO выделилась куча сайтов, а нам такого не видать. Надо вообще разрешить всё, что было хоть когда-то разрешено на SO, а потом уже разбираться.

Comment: @Kromster, кажется, аргументировал в комментарии...

Comment: @Qwertiy замечу, что очень многие вопросы по этой метке закрыты вовсе не с пометкой "не по теме", а с пометкой "нельзя дать объективно верный ответ" (в том числе вопрос с +27). В том, что касается работы, у нас слишком часты вопросы, единственно правильный ответ на которые "зависит от вашего работодателя" или "зависит лично от вас", а потому ответы на такие вопросы больше никому не помогут. Я пока что не видел ни одного хорошего вопроса о работе, дотягивающего до уровня Workplace.SE, где на подобной метке построено целое сообщество.

Comment: @D-side согласен по поводу причин закрытия, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [предыдущее обсуждение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1771/) и на [его результат](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2423/).

Comment: @D-side, неужели требование *возможности объективного ответа* еще живо (и действует)? Если да, то его надо поскорей выбросить.

Comment: @avp ну, оно есть в причинах закрытия. Как минимум покуда оно там, оно будет действовать, а скорее всего и далее, т. к. это очень неплохой признак для вопросов, которые могут помочь хоть кому-то кроме задающего. Если вы считаете, что это плохой признак, сформулируйте свою позицию на Мете отдельным предложением, будем думать. Я совершенно не против рассмотреть такой вариант, просто пока не вижу "с чего бы".

Comment: @D-side, как минимум сама формулировка "объективно верный" плоха, она как-то предполагает, что человек, который закрывает с ней вопрос, имеет доступ к абсолютной истине.

Comment: @avp в нём есть проблемы, да. Но до сегодняшнего дня он свою задачу ограждать нас от вопросов-холиваров и их аналогов успешно выполнял. Вы можете предложить что-то более точное?

Comment: @D-side, холивары - это не всегда плохо.

Comment: @Qwertiy здесь сделан сознательный выбор от них избавиться под корень. Где-нибудь ещё они, разумеется, могут быть уместны.

Comment: @D-side, к сожалению, ничего "лучше", чем *бредовый вопрос* (спам и т.п. также попадает сюда), в голову не приходит. В некоторых случаях, очевидно, что вопрос не понятен и требует уточнения (но такая причина есть). А все остальное по тематике IT в идеале должно быть отвечено.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я бы сказал, что мой вопрос про метку [tag:работа] и вопрос про вопросы, связанные с работой не так и тесно связаны. Я полагаю, что можно, допустим вопросы оставить, а метку оставить только для чтения (то есть её чтобы нельзя было присваивать новым вопросам, но можно было бы по ней искать и находить).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky что вы думаете по поводу моего [ответа](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4301/220571)?